# Why QueryAsync<int> method in sqline-net returns zeros?

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

Why this code returns a list full of zeros?

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;
List<int> result;
result = await conn.QueryAsync<int>("SELECT Col FROM Table");
```

*Note: Col is type of INTEGER.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type in `QueryAsync<T>` must be a reference type.

```
class Scalar {
    public int Col { get; set; }
}

SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;
List<Scalar> result;
result = await conn.QueryAsync<Scalar>("SELECT Col FROM Table");
```

Comment: `QueryAsync<T>` mustn't be a reference type. It has a constraint of `new()`, not `class`. `public Task<List<T>> QueryAsync<T> (string sql, params object[] args) where T : new ()`. Any type with a default constructor will do. `int` does apply to this requirement, otherwise the code shouldn't compile.

Comment: I have also expected it, but `conn.QueryAsync<int>` compiles successfully in my case (Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, Class Library for Windows 8.1 Store App).

Comment: Of course it does. `int` has an implicit default constructor. You can create a new value type using `new int()`.

Comment: The problem is that sqlite-net does not set a value of `int` (probably because it does not have a *Col* setter). Although the type in `QueryAsync<T>` can be value type and code is compiled, it is not functional, because the value is not initialized.

Comment: `Col` needs to match whatever the column name in the table is, or it will still be 0